# Moodle issue when testing with XAMPP

Tags: xampp, moodle

I get following error after setup the backup Moodle website in Xampp server. But that files are actually in the website directory!

[image: XAMPP Error output]

Apache error log (Xampp) shows the following error.

```
[php7:warn] [pid 7608:tid 1920] [client ::1:61517] PHP Warning:  require_once(C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test/cache/classes/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\cache\\lib.php on line 35
[php7:error] [pid 7608:tid 1920] [client ::1:61517] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test/cache/classes/config.php' (include_path='C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test/lib/pear;C:\\xampp\\php\\PEAR') in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\cache\\lib.php on line 35
```

Config.php is as follows

```
$CFG->dbtype    = 'mariadb';      // 'pgsql', 'mariadb', 'mysqli', 'sqlsrv' or 'oci'
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';     // 'native' only at the moment
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';  // eg 'localhost' or 'db.isp.com' or IP
$CFG->dbname    = 'test';     // database name, eg moodle
$CFG->dbuser    = 'root';   // your database username
$CFG->dbpass    = '';   // your database password
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://localhost/test';
$CFG->dataroot  = 'c:\xampp\htdocs\test-data';
```

What could be the reason for this issue?

More information:

I have setup a Moodle website in CentOS 7, nginx 1.16.1, php 7.2.31, MariaDB 10.3 server environment. For backup purpose there is an offsite CentOS 7 remote server and I rsync the Moodle website, data directory and the database to that server.

I wanted to test the backup and in my Windows PC I installed Xampp for Windows 7.2.31 and configured the above backup on this server. But I get this issue now. Also there is an another backup of the same Moodle website that archived using tar.gz (This backup is stored locally in a tape drive). This backup works in the same Xampp environment without any issues! Also fresh Moodle installation is works well!

I requested help regarding this in the Moodle forum. But didn't found a solution.